# How can I test firebase with permissions for all users?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

After a while I am back to Firebase. Security rules ...

```
{
  "rules": {
   ".read": "auth != null",
   ".write": "auth != null"
   }
}
```

... do not work anymore, or am I wrong? Default rules seem to be

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
      match /{document=**} {
          allow read, write: if false;
      }
  }
}
```

I would like to test database access for the first time and let all users read and write for a moment. But I keep getting "PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied". Same when I set "if true".

My code:

```
var database = firebase.database();
var ref = database.ref("scores");
var data = {
    name: "er",
    score: 101
 }
 firebase.auth().signInAnonymously().catch(function(error) {
 // Handle Errors here.
 var errorCode = error.code;
 var errorMessage = error.message;
    console.log(errorCode + " " + errorMessage);
 });
 ref.push(data);
 console.log("pushed");
```

What did I overlook?

Answer (score 1):

This rule is for firestore:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
      match /{document=**} {
          allow read, write: if false;
      }
  }
}
```

but in your code you are using realtime database `firebase.database()`, so change your rules to the following:

```
{
  "rules": {
   ".read": "true",
   ".write": "true"
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Peter for taking the time to fix such a mistake! Some time, when I registered the app I must have chosen Firestore. I just switched to Firebase and everything is fine!